# Automatic decodable synthesis for decodable property wrappers

Tags: swift, decodable, property-wrapper

Let's say I have decodable property wrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct OptionalDecodable<Value: Decodable>: Decodable {
  var wrappedValue: Value?
}
```

The compiler does synthesize init for the following

```
struct Model: Decodable {
  @OptionalDecodable private(set) var string: String?
}
```

To test if this works I just try to decode empty JSON (i.e. "{}")

However, `string` property is not treated as optional, i.e. when there's no `string` key I get an error that key was not found.

Is there a work around this?

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking. Can you add to the question the JSON that you're trying to decode? Also, why do you need this property wrapper? Optionals are already handled by Codable

Comment: @NewDev Updated the question, hope this helps.
The purpose of this wrapper is to perform custom decoding under the hood. Say, I want strings to be decoded properly from both strings and numbers. The idea works great with non-optional data types. But when it came to optionals, I got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but the issue is that `wrappedValue` type of the property wrapper has to match the property's type, and `String` is different than `String?`.

One approach to overcome this is to make the property wrapper generic, but constrain in such a way that would allow you to initialize the type from a `String` or an `Int`:

```
protocol ExpressibleByString {
    init(fromString: String)
}
extension String: ExpressibleByString {
    init(fromString: String) { self = fromString }
}
extension Optional: ExpressibleByString where Wrapped == String {
    init(fromString: String) { self = fromString }
}
```

```
@propertyWrapper
struct IntOrString<V: ExpressibleByString & Decodable>: Decodable {
    var wrappedValue: V
}

extension IntOrString {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        
        do {
            let int = try container.decode(Int.self)
            wrappedValue = .init(fromString: int.description)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            wrappedValue = try .init(fromString: container.decode(String.self))
        }
   }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode<V: ExpressibleByNilLiteral>(_ t: IntOrString<V>.Type, forKey key: K) throws -> IntOrString<V> {
        if let v = try decodeIfPresent(t, forKey: key) {
            return v
        }
        return IntOrString(wrappedValue: nil)
    }
}
```

Then you could use it on both optional and non-optional `String`:

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
    @IntOrString
    var p1: String?

    @IntOrString
    var p2: String
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I've written a test for your code: 
`let test = #"{ "p2": "value" }"#
let data = test.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
  let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from: data)
  print(object)
} catch {
  print(error)
}`
As you can see, property `p1` is missing in the test JSON. And the output is 
`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "p1", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"p1\", intValue: nil) (\"p1\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Which is the issue I am trying to resolve